# Configuração da fixture mocker em pytest-mock

Tags: python, mock

Eu gostaria de fazer testes utilizando o pytest-mock.
Já executei o comando pip install pytest-mock e instalou, porém quando executo o teste abaixo o pytest não consegue achar a fixture. O que pode ser?

```
import pytest    
def test_unix_fs(mocker):
    mocker.patch('os.remove')
    UnixFS.rm('file')
    os.remove.assert_called_once_with('file')
```

def test_unix_fs(mocker):
E       fixture 'mocker' not found

> ```
>   available fixtures: cache, capfd, capsys, doctest_namespace, get_attribute, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>   use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
> ```

Site do pytest-mock: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-mock